# Using SUM query to update table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using Access 2013 VBA.  I want to update sum quantity from tblSoldMonthRecord to tbl_POPLan.

Error message is "Operation must use an uneatable query." for below code.

```
str = "UPDATE tbl_POPLan INNER JOIN " & _
            "(SELECT Item, SUM(Qty) AS SumQty FROM tblSoldMonthRecord GROUP BY Item) AS A ON " & _
        "tbl_POPLan.Item = A.Item  " & _
        "SET tbl_POPLan.M0 = A.SumQty "

DoCmd.RunSQL str
```

If I remove SUM from SQL, it works.

```
str = "UPDATE tbl_POPLan INNER JOIN " & _
            "(SELECT Item, Qty AS SumQty FROM tblSoldMonthRecord) AS A ON " & _
        "tbl_POPLan.Item = A.Item  " & _
        "SET tbl_POPLan.M0 = A.SumQty "
```

How can I update sum  value to another table by RunSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is not updateable if it contains any aggregate function in query or in any of subqueries. As a workaround you can try to use domain functions instead of aggregate - in your case DSum or use temporary table with results of subquery with `Sum`